# Importing my methods so that AutoForm can see them

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

**I don't understand how to `import` my methods so that AutoForm can see them.** Based on the 1.3 best practices, all inserts/updates/deletes should be blocked on the client, and we should use methods instead. These should be imported on a page-by-page basis on the client.

I tried removing the quotes around the `meteormethod` attribute, and `import`ing the Method in the template's JS file, but this returns an error `method.js:11 Uncaught Error: When form type is "method", you must also provide a "meteormethod" attribute`.

What's the best practice for this? How do I tell AutoForm where to find my method?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own problem. Don't `import` anything, just reference the **internal `Meteor` method name** in AutoForm's `meteormethod` attribute.

For example (if you're using `ValidatedMethod`):

```
export const insertProject = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'projects.insert',
  validate: Projects.schema.validator(),
  run(fields) {
    Projects.insert(fields);
  }
});
```

You'd then use:

```
{{> quickForm collection=projects id="insertProjectForm" type="method" meteormethod="projects.insert"}}
```

(note the `meteormethod` attribute is the same as the `name` attribute of the `ValidatedMethod`)

Ref: https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-validated-methods/